# Игнорирование delete для указателя на объект в статической памяти

Tags: c++

"Использование оператора delete на указателе на объект, который не был создан при помощи оператора new, создает непрогнозируемый результат." (сайт MSDN Microsoft)

Есть ли способ сделать этот результат прогнозируемым (то есть простое игнорирование этой операции)? Например, чтобы:

```
int x = 5;
int* pt = &x;
delete(pt);
```

был равнозначен этому же коду без `delete`?

**Обновление**

Допустим, одно из полей класса Class есть массив Arr указателей на объекты класса Class2, причем часть этих объектов могут быть в динамической памяти, а часть - в статической.

При написании деструктора для Class хотелось бы пройтись по массиву Arr и, если данный указатель указывает на объект Class2 в динамической памяти, освободить место от этого объекта Class2.

Цикл

```
for (int i=0;i<=Arr_index;i++)
{
  delete(Arr[i]);
}
```

работает только в случае, если все объекты по указателям - в динамической памяти.

Comment: Не понятно, что вы хотите достичь. Вы можете применять оператор delete к объектам, созданным с помощью оператора new. Зачем вы пытаетесь что-то удалить, что создано самим компилятором?

Comment: `#define delete(x)` // а вообще, не занимайтесь ерундой.

Comment: а почему ерунда? нормальный вопрос в целом) возможно ли создать безопасный delete который не приводит к UB если передали невалидный указатель в куче.

Comment: Для создания безопасного `delete` надо либо проверять, что указатель ведёт в stdlib-ную кучу (а это чёрная магия и потрошение платформозависимой стандартной библиотеки), либо оказывать активное содействие со стороны указываемого объекта, вводя что-то наподобие `IUnknown`.

Comment: @Arhad: Причём не обязательно в stdlib'ную? Вон на Windows возможно несколько heap'ов у одного процесса.

Comment: @Arhad: Хуже того, даже если указатель и ведёт в heap, то объект может быть полем какого-нибудь класса, расположенного в heap'е.

Comment: @VladD `Причём не обязательно в stdlib'ную` — это всё implementation-defined, что, прочем, не добавляет радости.

Comment: @pavel самый безопасный `delete` - тот, который не надо писать. Читай как "используйте смарт-поинтеры". Будь обход UB переносимо возможен, его бы не было в стандарте.

Comment: @VladD `... то объект может быть полем какого-нибудь класса ...` — удачно я, однако, COM с его `IUnknown` упомянул. Ведь `IClassFactory` как раз и позволяет указать, что создаваемый объект является частью некоего aggregate и подсчёту ссылок не подлежит. Но в C++ такого механизма нет, согласен.

Comment: @alexolut, а как объявить умный указатель, способный попеременно хранить владеющие и невладеющие ссылки? Ведь в вопросе шла речь именно о подобной разнородности указателя.

Comment: @Arhad `std::variant<std::shared_ptr, std::weak_ptr>` ?

Answer (score 5):

Выполнять `delete x` можно безопасно только в том случае, если для `x` заранее был выполнен `new`. Какого-то простого и переносимого способа определить только лишь по значению указателя относится он к куче или стеку не существует.

Решение "в лоб" могло бы подразумевать перегрузку глобальных операторов `new` и `delete` таким образом, чтобы `new` обеспечивал сохранение адреса в некую таблицу, а `delete` проверял бы наличие этого адреса там, и если не смог найти, то просто ничего бы не делал.

Но сдаётся мне, что решаете вы совсем другую задачу и в текущей интерпретации просто упёрлись в [проблему XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/176217).

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, читал в книжке Страуструпа про программирование - "Принципы программирования", кажеится, так там у него в одном месте был хитрый вектор с указателями, которые часть надо было освобождать, а другие - нет (как тут), так он вынужден был вводить дополнительный флаг, что с этим указателем делать.

Уж если сам Страуструп так поступает, то что нам остается? :)